# searching a substring in a python list and then removing it from the list

Tags: python, list, search

I have a python list like:

```
['A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/packaging/DEBIAN/control', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/create_cosmos_installer.sh', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/packaging/DEBIAN/control', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/scripts/create_skyline_installer.sh', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/forms.py', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/tables.py', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/templates/flavors/_create.html',
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/templates/flavors/_edit.html',
'A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/scripts/create_skyline_installer.sh',
'A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/forms.py', 
'A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/tables.py', 
'A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/templates/flavors/_create.html']
```

Now the first character of each string is either `A` or `M`. Apart from this first letter, some of the strings are identical: for example the two strings ending with `create_skyline_installer.sh`, 5th from the top and 4th from the bottom.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to find strings where after `A` or `M` the rest of the body of the string is same. Then I want to remove the list element which is starting with `M`.

I mean the final list should look like this:

```
['A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/packaging/DEBIAN/control', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/create_cosmos_installer.sh', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/packaging/DEBIAN/control', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/scripts/create_skyline_installer.sh',
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/forms.py', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/tables.py', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/templates/flavors/_create.html',
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/templates/flavors/_edit.html']
```

But I am unable to find a solution.

Please help me out.

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Here is a direction - try regex to find strings that begin with M

Comment: Rather than copying and pasting the whole list, why can't you just create something smaller than denotes what you wanted to achieve? My eyes really hurts to see this mesh.

Comment: Jack_of_All_Trades :  Thanks for the suggestion. I edited the list.. Please try to help me, if you can. Thank You...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to sort the list, where `A` elements will be processed before the `M` elements, and use a dictionary to save them, so the first entries will be overwritten. Use `reverse=True` to keep the `A` entries.

```
lst = ['A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal (from /cloudos-ui/branches/rc4g1build:9930)',                            
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/misc/cosmos/packaging/DEBIAN/control', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/misc/cosmos/scripts/create_cosmos_installer.sh', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/misc/skyline/packaging/DEBIAN/control', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/misc/skyline/scripts/create_skyline_installer.sh',
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/forms.py', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/tables.py', 
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/templates/flavors/_create.html',
'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/templates/flavors/_edit.html',
'A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/misc/skyline/scripts/create_skyline_installer.sh',
'A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/forms.py', 
'A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/tables.py', 
'A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/templates/flavors/_create.html']

d = {}

for elem in sorted(lst):
    l = elem.split(None, 1)
    d[l[1]] = elem

print(list(d.values()))
```

It yields:

```
['A /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal (from /cloudos-ui/branches/rc4g1build:9930)',
 'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/templates/flavors/_edit.html',
 'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/forms.py',
 'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/tables.py',
 'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/misc/cosmos/packaging/DEBIAN/control',
 'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/src/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/flavors/templates/flavors/_create.html',
 'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/misc/skyline/packaging/DEBIAN/control',
 'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/misc/cosmos/scripts/create_cosmos_installer.sh',
 'M /cloudos-ui/branches/bare_metal/misc/skyline/scripts/create_skyline_installer.sh']
```

Comment: Thank You but it is also removing the prefix `A` or `M`. I want them in the final output.. Please can You tell what could be done more to retain them?

Comment: @NikunjAggarwal: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean. Which prefix?

Comment: the `A` or `M` is there in the front of each string... I want to retain them after removing the duplicates...

Comment: @NikunjAggarwal: They appear in my output. Have you tested it? How does it appear in yours?

Comment: Thank You, it is working... I was writing the output in the file so i use `d` instead of `list(d.values())`, that is why i was not getting the prefixes. But i changed it and now i am getting. Thank You.